# Where is useSSL=false located?

Tags: mysql

I recently got this error:

```
Thu Sep 27 23:12:40 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without 
server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 
5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default 
if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not 
using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need 
either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true 
and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

I have asked everywhere and I don't know where `useSSL=false` is.
Can someone please tell me, It may seem stupid, but I'm new to Ubuntu and I've been trying this for hours.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to describe the context in which this error message occurred? Thanks.